# ubuntu 17.10 displayport 1.2

Tags: 17.10, monitor, gpu-driver

So I just got one of those nice samsung ultrawide 49" monitors and an ATI card to go with it only to find out that trying to use the displayport version other then 1.1 completely fails and leaves the screen on but no display. Is this a known issue? It's really annoying when you dual boot and windows needs 1.2 otherwise it looks all fuzzy. This is a fresh install too. Wondering if the 3840x1080 resolution is messing things up. Once i'm logged in if I switch to 1.2 or 1.2a it'll just go blank and I'll have to force reboot to get back to the monitor controls.

Answer (score 0):

DisplayPort 1.2 added support for Multi-Stream Transport (MST), enabling multiple monitors to be used via a single DisplayPort connector. This function requires either monitors that are capable of DisplayPort 1.2 daisy-chaining, or use of a DisplayPort MST Hub. The first MST hub became available in September 2013, enabling up to 3 displays to be connected to a single DisplayPort connector.[33]

Single Stream Transport (SST) was specified in DisplayPort 1.1a for use between a single Source and Sink Device.

Ref: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort#Dual-mode_DisplayPort

Comment: this doesn't explain much to me. I'm not trying to daisy chain here. This is a single monitor that has that resolution.

Answer (score 0):

If I try to use DP1.2 with 144 Hz refresh rate it all goes sideways. Lowering that down to 120 Hz seems to have fixed the issue and still use DP 1.2

(Not sure if this is a known issue as I can't find anyone talking about it.)